# Ruby: Can I use "or"( || ) more than once in one statement?

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm trying to make a blackjack game using Ruby and am trying to make the values of the picture cards all = 10. Is it okay to use the code I use below to accomplish this? (this is all happening in my `Card` class)

```
def value
  if @number == ("jack" || "queen" || "king")
    10
  else
    @number.to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, but not the way you are using it.  You either need to use the entire boolean expression in each portion:

```
if @number == "jack" || @number == "queen" || @number == "king"
```

or you can make it simpler by checking the contents of an array:

```
if ["jack", "queen", "king"].include?(@number)
```

Comment: or even easier-to-write: `if %w{jack queen king}.include?(@number)`

Answer (score 5):

The parens group things that should be evaluated before other things. So, the above says, evaluate:

```
 ("jack" || "queen" || "king")
```

and return the results. Lets try that in irb:

```
irb(main):004:0> ("jack" || "queen" || "king")
=> "jack"
```

Since "jack" is truthy there's no need to look at the rest of the list and "jack" is returned.

This will work fine as long as @number is equal to "jack" but not so much for the other values. You want to compare @number against each value until you get a match or exhaust the list. See @PinneyM's answer of

```
(@number == "jack") || (@number == "queen") ...
```

Comment: I may start using the word 'truthy'.

Comment: yeah, in a boolean context it acts as if it were true, whose class is really TrueClass, but it's actually not strictly speaking true, so truthy.

Answer (score 2):

That is a valid ruby snippet, but it doesn't do what you think it does: it first evaluates

```
 ("jack" || "queen" || "king")
```

which evaluates to "jack" as that is the first non false/nil value. It then compares `@card` to this, so your code is equivalent to

```
def value
  if @number == 'jack'
    10
  else
    @number.to_i
  end
end
```

You could compare each in turn `(@number == 'jack') || (@number == 'queen') ||...`, you could use `%w(jack queen king).include?(@number)` or you could use a case statement:

```
def value
  case @number
  when 'jack', 'queen', 'king'
    10
  else
    @number.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: yeh i eventually ended up using your def value case example on the bottom. it worked. thanks